# LINQ: Select a column based on another column value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

After executing some LINQs, I have this data as `IQueryable` of an anonymous type:

```
Cat  Type  Count
----------------
A     1     10
B     1     15
C     1     25
D     1     5
A     2     15
C     2     30
D     2     20
B     2     10
```

Now, for every Cat I want to select Count based on Type values with LINQ.

Output should be like this:

```
Cat  Type1Count  Type2Count
---------------------------
A       10           15
B       15           10
C       25           30 
D       5            20
```

Comment: What have you tried? We´re not here to do your job, which is *thinking*, *trying*, *thinking again*.

Comment: Define "like this". Is the `Type` column constrained to 1 and 2, or do you actually want to pivot?

Comment: Hi Amir, you are in this community since over 4 years, you have asked 14 questions and did not mark any accepted answers. No offense, but at this point you should actually know that the community does not really appriciate to be treated as a code writing service where you dump requirements and harvest working code. You could have at least posted 1 attempt

Comment: @MongZhu My friend, most of my questions have no answer or only one answer which is not my accepted answer. What should I do? Should I accept an answer which is not my accepted one? Anyway, maybe it's my mistake and I do my best to correctly cooperate in this community from now on. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: if the answers that you get are not satisfying then of course you should not accept them. I take this one back. But the first attempt to solve the problem on your own issue still remains valid. It just does not make a good impression when the post looks like leeching on the peoples generousity. Happy coding mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `groupby` then `select` to do pivot.

```
var query = myList
    .GroupBy(c => c.Cat)
    .Select(g => new {
        Cat  = g.Key,
        Type1Count = g.Where(a => a.Type == 1).Sum(c => c.Count),
        Type2Count = g.Where(a => a.Type == 2).Sum(c => c.Count)
    });
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jDprPS)

**Result**

```
Cat:A  Type1Count:10  Type2Count:15
Cat:B  Type1Count:15  Type2Count:10
Cat:C  Type1Count:25  Type2Count:30
Cat:D  Type1Count:5  Type2Count:20
```

Comment: For your fiddle & results, you seem to have misread that for type 2, rows go `ACDB` in OP sample. Otherwise it would have lead to the same result as expected by OP. I didn't vote on your answer, but I believe the one downvote you got is because you answered a question that should be closed for no attempt

Comment: @D-Shih Thanks my friend

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to group by Cat and Type and get sum of Count:

```
myList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Cat, x.Type }).Select(x => new { Cat = x.Key.Cat, Type = x.Key.Type, CountForTypeAndCat = x.Sum(y=>y.Count) })
```

This will allow you go get information for any Type not only 1 and 2

```
foreach (var item in query.OrderBy(x=>x.Cat).ThenBy(x=>x.Type))
{
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Cat:{0}  Type:{1}  CountForTypeAndCat:{2}", item.Cat, item.Type, item.CountForTypeAndCat));
}
```